# Refresh current fragment from MainActivity

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, fragment

I would that when I add a new item in the `ListView`, the fragment is refreshed.

I have read a lot of post's but anything. I have tried to add:

```
fragTransaction.detach(currentFragment);
fragTransaction.attach(currentFragment);
fragTransaction.commit();
```

or other things, but I can't do it.

Here is the Fragment :

```
public class GiocatoFragment extends Fragment {

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v  = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_giocato, null);
    ListView giocatoList = (ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.listView_giocato);

    Cursor cursor = MainActivity.userDb.getGames(ClasseDiAppoggio.getConsole(), "Giocato");
    String[] fromFieldNames = new String[] {UserDataBase.COL_VIDEOGAME_NAME, UserDataBase.COL_VIDEOGAME_DEVELOPER, UserDataBase.COL_VIDEOGAME_VALUE};
    int[] toViewsIDs = new int[] {R.id.textView_game_name, R.id.textView_developper, R.id.textView_value};
    SimpleCursorAdapter myCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this.getContext(), R.layout.game_row, cursor, fromFieldNames, toViewsIDs, 0);
    giocatoList.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);

    return v;
}

@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);


    if (isVisibleToUser) {
        ClasseDiAppoggio.setItem("Giocato");
    }
}

}
```

Here is the method where the item is added in the db.

```
    private void addGame(String game, String console) {


    myDb.getGame(game);

    userDb.addGame(console, game, ClasseDiAppoggio.getItem());

    TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    txt.setText(DataBase.gameInfo[0] + ", " + DataBase.gameInfo[1]);




}
```

How can I do?

Comment: If you are talking about an actual `ListView` that has an `Adapter` then all you need to do is call `adapter.notifyDatasetChanged()` after adding or removing items from it.

Comment: As adapter i use simpleCursorAdapter in the fragment..

Comment: Is that what `myDb` is?  If so, all you need to do is call `myDb.requery()` I believe.  `requery` is what you use for `SimpleCursorAdapter` rather than `notifyDatasetChanged()`

Comment: And where should i put it?

Comment: Put a `userDb.requery()` call right after the  `userDb.addGame()` call, if userDb is the adapter.  If not, you'll need to get the adapter var from the ListView first.

Answer (score 0):

if you are getting the arraylist in activity or fetching from db in activity, then from activity you can send a local broadcast from activity to fragment  and can receive that broadcast in fragment and can fetch the data from db and from here you can manipulate the list and can notify list, else you can make a method in fragment and call call from the instance of that fragment from activity and inside that method you can fetch the list from db and can show it.

Comment: Sorry but i don't understend what do u mean